# Clarification on the definition of a smooth scheme over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm confused on the following definition of smoothness in Ravi Vakil's notes.

[image]

What is meant by "at all points?"  At all $k$-rational points of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1, ... , x_n]/(f_1, ... , f_r)$?  Or do we mean the rank of the matrices $(\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} + \mathfrak p) \in \textrm{Mat}_{r\times n}(\operatorname{Frac}k[x_1, ... , x_n]/\mathfrak p)$, where $\mathfrak p$ runs through the primes containing $(f_1, ... ,f_t)$?

The second definition is much more restrictive than the first, since for a scheme of finite type over a field $k$, the $k$-rational points can be identified with the points of the scheme whose residue field is exactly $k$, rather than an algebraic extension of $k$ (general closed point).

Comment: Shouldn't it be about the (co)rank of the matrix $M_{i,j}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f_i(x)$ at every $x \in \overline{k}^n, \forall i, f_i(x) =0$ ?

Comment: I think this is true (basically the result that $X$ is smooth over $k$ if and only if $X_{\overline k}$ is smooth over $\overline k$), but the definition I'm trying to understand here doesn't seem to involve $\overline k$ at all.

Comment: This is just saying that the $(n-d)\times(n-d)$ minors of the Jacobian matrix generate the unit ideal in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$.

Comment: Why?  $\space \space$

Comment: $R = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I, I =(f_1,\ldots,f_r)$, for some $a\in \overline{k}^n,I(a) = 0$ take a maximal ideal such that $R/\mathfrak{p} \cong k(a_1,\ldots,a_n), x+\mathfrak{p} \to a$, then $ M(x) + \mathfrak{p} \to M(a)$, so my comment is the same as your second criterion with $\mathfrak{p}$ runring over maximal ideals

Comment: To answer your `Why', points correspond to all maximal ideals (equivalently all prime ideals), and the non-vanishing of the minors of the Jacobian precisely says what I said.

Comment: Okay, so for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$, there exists a minor of size $n - d$ which does not lie in $\mathfrak m$, i.e. the image of the minor is nonzero in $R/\mathfrak m$.  So the ideal generated by the minors is not contained in any maximal ideal, then generates the unit ideal in $R$.